# Unity Crashes when Using this UI

Tags: unity-game-engine

using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine;

public class Tutorial : MonoBehaviour
{
public Text tutorialText;

```
void Update()
{
    tutorialText.text = "Press [SPACE] to Jump... (obviously...)";
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        while (true)
        {
            tutorialText.text = "Now Shoot";
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    tutorialText.text = "Nice";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Remove the two `while (true)`.

Comment: I want to make this like a Tutorial. If I remove it, it shows "Now Shoot" for a Frame and Switches back to "Press [SPACE] to jump..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to that, because right now you are in a infinite loop which sets your tutorialtext to "Now Shoot" again and again until Unity crashes.

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
{
   tutorialText.text = "Now Shoot";
}
else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
{
   tutorialText.text = "Nice";
}
```

If you want the text to disappear after the first time you done the actions you should add bool variables.

```
bool jumped = false;
bool hasShot = false;
```

And then implement thoose bools into your code like this:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
{
   if (jumped)
      return;

   tutorialText.text = "Now Shoot";
   jumped = true;
}
else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
{
   if (hasShot || !jumped)
      return;

   tutorialText.text = "Nice";
   hasShot = true;
}
```

You also need to move the first text definition out of Update, because Update is called each frame. Put it into `void Start()` instead

```
void Start() {
   tutorialText.text = "Press [SPACE] to Jump... (obviously...)";
}
```

Comment: Im not sure if Im doing it wrong. But I copied your script. Now I have the other problem again. It Switches for a Frame to "Now Shoot" and then back to "Press [SPACE] to Jump... (obviously...)"

Comment: Edited my post you need to move the first definition of tutorialtext out of update into the start method.

Comment: It kind of works. But I have a last "Bug". If I shoot right at the beginning, it Skips the first two definitions and jumps to "Nice"